# Kinetic JS: Can I add multiple names to shapes?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I have the following for example to create a polygon:

```
            var poly = new Kinetic.Polygon({
                x: coorx,
                y: coory,
                points: coords,
                alpha: 0,
                fill: colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)],
                name: myname
            });
```

What I would like to do is have two class names, for example "rect-1" and "rect-2". I want some of the shapes to have one of those classes, some will have both.

The point of this would be to be able to use the `get()` syntax to transition some shapes in one way, opacity for example, and other shapes in another way, offset for example:

Is it possible to gives shapes multiple "class" names for advanced selection as I described here?

Thanks!

```
    var shapes = stage.get(".rect-1");

    for(var n = 0; n < shapes.length; n++) {
        var shape = shapes[n];

        shape.transitionTo({
            alpha: (opacities[Math.floor(Math.random() * opacities.length)] * 1.5) + .7,
            duration: 2
        });                 
    }

    var shapes = stage.get(".rect-2");

    for(var n = 0; n < shapes.length; n++) {
        var shape = shapes[n];

        shape.transitionTo({
            offset: {
                x: 10,
                y: 10
            },
            duration: 2
        });                 
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This object filtering is not built-in yet, but one easy implementation could be to iterate through the stage children with the `getChildren()` method and test a conditional in this loop like

`if shape.get('classList') && shape.get('classList').indexOf('rect1') !== -1`

Another solution with mono inheritance could be to subclass the Kinetic.Rect class using the `extend()` method and overload the `shapeType` attribute, which will become the key for your filtering.

Answer (score 8):

Interesting use case!  I'll add this to my todo list.  perhaps something like this:

```
var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
   name: 'foo bar test'
});
```

would assign three different names (similar to DOM class name strings)

Comment: IS this feature available in the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

The Kinetic function is publicly accessible, so you can easily overwrite it with your own version. Here's how I fixed it.

```
Kinetic._addName = function(node, name) {
    if(name !== undefined) {
        var names = name.split(/\W+/g);
        for(var n = 0; n < names.length; n++) {
            if (names[n]) {
                if(this.names[names[n]] === undefined) {
                    this.names[names[n]] = [];
                }
                this.names[names[n]].push(node);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Eric, if you like it, feel free to add it to Kinetic. I might submit a pull request soon.